# Changing Angular Carousel Position with Directive->controller change not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-carousel

I am trying to create some event triggers to change the position of an Angular Carousel ([Github repo](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel)).

[See the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I2ixpK?p=info) for a working version

The expected behavior is that you click the text that says "Go to position: 0" and the Carousel will change index position to 0.

This is accomplished using two-way binding on the Carousel: `rn-carousel-index="carouselIndex"`

This scope value is passed to a directive by setting: `carousel-index="carouselIndex"`

A controller method to modify `carouselIndex` is also passed to the directive with: `index-model="indexModel(value)"`

The directive takes the scopes and has a function bound to the text that should change the Carousel position:

```
app.directive('timeline', function () {
  return {
    replace:true,
    scope:{
     indexModel:'&',
     carouselIndex:'='
    },

    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {


          var valueto = 0;

        var textElement = d3.select(".timeLine").text('Go to position: ' + valueto)
        textElement
          .on('click',clickMe)

        function clickMe(d){
          console.log('click');
          console.log("but index is: " + scope.carouselIndex);

          scope.carouselIndex = valueto;
         // scope.$apply(carouselIndex) = valueto;
          scope.indexModel({value: valueto});
          //alert(d);
        }

    }
  }
})
```

As you can see, when you click, the watcher on `$carouselIndex` does not always change. Moreover, and more importantly, the Carousel behavior to change position is not working.

```
$scope.$watch('carouselIndex', function(a,b) {
      console.log('change detected');
      console.log('Index really is: ' + $scope.carouselIndex);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `digest()` `$apply()` function solved the problem.

```
    $scope.indexModel = function(slide) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log('change slide ' + slide);

        var changeSlide = parseInt(slide);
        $scope.carouselIndex = changeSlide;
        console.log('Index should be: ' + $scope.carouselIndex);
     )}
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem with the watcher on `$scope.carouselIndex`, try what the Docs say

```
Note: If the indicators don't seem to update with the slides, try binding to an object param i.e. carousel.index, set in the controller like $scope.carousel.index = 0
```

https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel